# UWP intercept Webview POST request and get the content

Tags: c#, post, webview, uwp, request

Using UWP/XAML, I'm trying to intercept WebView's POST (form and file upload) request by handling WebResourceRequested and get the contents to be saved, but the Content keep shows '<unbuffered>' in the Local Window and cannot be accessed. How can I get access to the Content?

```
private void WebView_WebResourceRequested(WebView sender, WebViewWebResourceRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (request.Method.Method == "POST")
    {
        HttpStreamContent content = (HttpStreamContent) args.request.Content;
        var contentBuffer = content.ReadAsBufferAsync().GetResults();
        byte[] buffer = contentBuffer.ToArray();
    }                    
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have your tried to add the post  uri to [content uris](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#interacting-with-web-view-content).

Comment: I tried to get the actual body of html POST request that contain form submission and content of uploaded files. It should be in the Content property with a stream object to be accessed with, but the value always '<unbuferred>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UWP intercept Webview POST request and get the content

This is know issue in WebView1.
Currently, we provided a workaround that use `ReadAsInputStreamAsync` to get request content  and use fixed length to load buffer. Because it is un-seek stream. I tested with success on the simple repro sample we have.

```
 private async void MyWebView_WebResourceRequested(WebView sender, WebViewWebResourceRequestedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Request.Method.Method == "POST")
        {

            if (args.Request.Content != null)
            {
                var bodyStream = await args.Request.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();
                var buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(4096);
                await bodyStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 4096, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.None);
                var reader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                var len = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
                var body = reader.ReadString(len);

                Debug.WriteLine($"Body from POST request: {body}");

            }            
        }
    }
```

Of course, this code will work as long as we provide a buffer large enough for the post data. Here a buffer of 4096 bytes is enough to get the entire data posted, for this sample.

Comment: So it is available as input stream. I though it already has all the content sent in the buffer. Thanks. I'm glad it is still managed so I don't have to wait for WebView2.

Comment: But it cannot read content of uploaded file. I wonder if there is any workaround. Or it is not covered on HttpRequestMessage in the first place.

Comment: @yosimadsu, yep, I know that, I’m afraid the workaround can’t work that way. You need to size the buffer correctly before calling ReadAsync.

Comment: I've tried many things to get the http POST multipart to be read, but seems it is the limit of WebView control. Probably I do need to wait for WebView2 and try the same thing, or I have to make my own webview instead. Thanks.